# Getting null value for variable using CSS/JQuery Extractor and regular expression extractor

Tags: jmeter

I need to collect this number: 1239 . It is displayed on Responde data:

```
< li id="1239" >
```

In this line:

```
options_anchor_569738631.hrefparameter = "searchResults.struts.token=token&struts.token.name=searchResults.struts.token&subscriberId=1234&initialize=true&id=1239&accountId=1234&locationTag=&selectedTypeName=Generic&selectedTab=0";
```

I tried CSS/JQuery Extractor and Regular Expression Extractor, But I probably did something wrong.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Regular Expression Extractor

```
 id="(\d+)
```

Template $1$
Regular Expression Extractor
Match 1